# Writing a contraposition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write a justification by constrapostion to show that  for any real number x

$x^2+2x<0 \rightarrow x<0$

then contrapositive

$x\ge 0 \rightarrow x^2+2x\ge0$

The justifcation I can say is that the zeroes of $x^2+2x$ are at $x=0 \wedge x=-2$

so if you your x is zero then your result will always be greater than zero.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You say if $x$ is zero, then the result will always be greater than $0$. That isn't true, maybe you meant something else. Now the question remains what happens when $x>0$. It follows that then $2x >0$ and $x^2>0$ (since the product of positive reals is positive).

Comment: yes sorry I mean when x greater than or equal to zero then x^2+2x will be greater than zero.

Comment: You just calculated the zeroes, you cannot conclude from that what you said above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \geq 0 \implies x^2+2x \geq 0^2+2(0)=0$.